# What is this sharp, curved notch on my knife for?

Tags: knives

I recently bought a knife that near the handle end of the blade has a sharp, curved part:

[image]

I don’t think it’s a [choil](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/choil) because it’s sharp. What is its use? I thought something to do with stripping sinew from bones maybe?

It is a PBK Brute Lock Knife MH-689.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21954/how-to-sharpen-the-line-cutter-gut-hook-on-a-knife

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a **line cutter**, the idea is that you use it to cut lines, string etc. **The reason that it's curved is to keep the line from slipping off the blade**, using the rest of the blade would be quite difficult to do.

See [here](https://www.jayfisher.com/Knife_Anatomy_Parts_Names_Definitions.htm) for more examples.

You wouldn't want to use it for skinning.

Comment: Thanks. Why wouldn’t I want to use it for skinning?

Comment: @Darren Because there are basically no times where you would want to skin around something that fits perfectly into the notch and otherwise the blade wouldn't be touching what it needs to cut